# Having trouble making sense of example problem the way it's written

Tags: calculus

[issue Solved, type in exmpl. problem answer.]

The way [this example problem](http://i949.photobucket.com/albums/ad332/Fractur65/ex1.png) is written I'm just reading it wrong or if I've messed something up. Am I wrong or should that last part be $6 \cdot17 + 5$?

Comment: You're right, it should be "+" not "–", so "the smallest it can be" is 102 not 97.

Comment: You're welcome. I always like it when people have trouble making sense of falsehoods :)

Comment: Lol. I'm just glad I have this site to help a bit. Sometimes I'm staring at math problems so long I'm not sure if it's me or the problem itself. XD

Comment: @BrianO I think "the smallest it can be" should be 107, not 102...isn't it? :-)

Comment: Yea. Cause 102 is the 17*6, then +5 so 107.

Comment: @Aniket and I think you're right (oops! hasty)